# if I use <meta http-equiv="refresh" content=""> to force a page refresh without a time value will it work

Tags: html, tags, meta

I have a friend that has customers that have not set their browser properties to view a current page upon load and are looking at dated pages in a cache and getting old information. These people are seeing dated business hours and product information. He asked if I knew of a way to force a page refresh in the page html code that would result in a single refresh upon load. If I do not set a time value and leave the quotes as "" will that force the refresh only once?

I tried leaving no time value between the quotes after content but do not know if it is working

I just want to force a single refresh upon load of a web page using HTML if possible and Javascript if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to insert this script in the page  - but any change to a page may not work at all if the browser does not read a new version of it

Remove
`https://www.google.com/search?q=x") //`
and the alert when you want to use it

```js
var URL = new URL("https://www.google.com/search?q=x") //location.href),
  parms = URL.searchParams;
  
if (!parms.has("new")) {
  parms.set("new",new Date().getTime())
  alert("Redirecting to "+URL.href)
  location.replace(URL.href);
}
```